# Error flask-sqlalchemy NameError: global name 'joinedload' is not defined

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to use a sqlalchemy loading strategy to speed up my queries. After reading [this](http://www.tracelytics.com/blog/advanced-sqlalchemy-performance-concerns/) I realized that I was making the mistake of looping through the records in my template. The only problem is that i get this error:

> NameError: global name 'joinedload' is not defined.

Is this happening because I'm using flask-sqlalchemy or em I forgetting to import something?

Models.py:

```
inspection_violations = db.Table('inspection_violations',
db.Column('violation_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('violations.violation_number')),
db.Column('inspection_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('inspection.inspection_id')), )

class Inspection(db.Model):
    inspection_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    violations = db.relationship('Violations', secondary=inspection_violations, backref=db.backref('inspection', lazy='dinamic'))
    facility_id = db.Column(db.String(100), db.ForeignKey('facilities.branch_name'))

class Violations(db.Model):
    violation_number = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    details  = db.Column(db.Text)
```

Violation Blueprint:

```
@violations_blueprint.route('/violations/<int:violation_number>')
def show_single_violation(violation_number):
    violation = Violations.query.options(joinedload('inspection')).get(violation_number)
    return render_template('violations/single-violation.html' ,violation=violation)
```

Template:

```
{% for inspection in violation.inspection %} 
  <p><a href="{{ url_for('inspection_blueprint.show_inspection', id=inspection.inspection_id) }}">    {{ inspection.facilities.branch_name }}</a></p>
{% endfor %}
```

To give some context to my models I have a inspection record. Every inspection has one or more violations. And every violation has many inspections

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Well, the error message says `joinedload` is not defined, so the obvious solution would be to check if you imported it and if not -

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import joinedload
```

Comment: Hey Bibhas, thanks. I just wasn't if sure it was getting imported  or where to import from since I'm using the flask extension.

Comment: `flask-sqlalchemy` is using `sqlalchemy` underneath. So you can always import modules from it.

Comment: @Bibhas Although what you are saying is correct 100%, Flask-SQLAlchemy also imports everything to `db`, so maybe you can use that too.

Comment: Thank you, I now know that even though I'm using the extension it still can import the same way. @jadikik94, you're right, that's why I was getting confused from where to import

Answer (score 0):

On my condition, it's just a order problem

```
class Inspection(db.Model):

class Violations(db.Model):

inspection_violations = ()     //wrong junction table position
```

this will not work too.because when you use inspection_violations it's not defined yet. and will also report the same problem

simply change the order will make it work

```
inspection_violations = ()   //right junction table position

class Inspection(db.Model):

class Violations(db.Model):
```

this is the right way to do this.